# Determine the common period

Tags: periodic-functions

Let $V = \mathrm{Vect}( e^{ 4 \pi it } , e^{ 5 \pi i t} , e^{ 6 \pi i t} ) $ and $f \in V$.

I want to determine the common period between the functions : $t \mapsto e^{ 4 \pi it } $, $t \mapsto e^{ 5 \pi i t }$ and $t \mapsto e^{ 6 \pi i t}$ ; i.e the period of $f \in V$.

We have

- $ t \mapsto e^{ 4 \pi i t} $ is periodic with period $\frac{1}{2}$
- $ t \mapsto e^{ 5 \pi i t} $ is periodic with period $\frac{2}{5}$
- $ t \mapsto e^{ 6 \pi i t} $ is periodic with period $\frac{1}{3}$

and I don't know how to pursue it. Is there a particular method to found a common period? I need a hint.

Thank you

Comment: lcm works for rational numbers too

Comment: @lhf 
$$ \mathrm{lcm}( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{3} ) = \mathrm{lcm}( \frac{1}{2}, \mathrm{lcm}( \frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{3} ) )  $$
Now $$ \mathrm{lcm}( \frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{3} )  = \frac{ \frac{2}{5} \frac{1}{3} }{ \mathrm{gcd}( \frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{3} ) } = 2 $$
Then
$$ \mathrm{lcm}( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{1}{3} ) = \mathrm{lcm}( \frac{1}{2}, 2 ) = \frac{2}{2} \mathrm{lcm}( \frac{1}{2}, 2 ) = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{lcm}( 1, 4 ) = \frac{4}{2} = 2 $$
It is correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: You can use that

$$\operatorname{lcm}\biggl(\frac pq,\frac rs\biggr)=\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(p,r)}{\gcd(q,s)}.$$

Comment: $$ \mathrm{lcm} (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{5} , \frac{1}{3} )= \mathrm{lcm} (\frac{1}{2}, \mathrm{lcm} ( \frac{2}{5} , \frac{1}{3} ) ) $$
Now
$$ \mathrm{lcm} ( \frac{2}{5} , \frac{1}{3} ) = \frac{ \mathrm{lcm} ( 2,1) }{ \mathrm{gcd}(5,3) } = \frac{2}{ \mathrm{gcd}(5,3)  \mathrm{gcd} ( 2,1)  } = 2  $$
Then 
$$ \mathrm{lcm} (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{5} , \frac{1}{3} )= \mathrm{lcm} (\frac{1}{2}, 2) = 2$$
Thank you

Comment: It is associative, as for integers: you could do it in a single stroke: $\dfrac{\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,1)}{\gcd(2,3,5)}$

Answer (score 1):

The periods are
$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{3}$.

Since $\operatorname{lcm}(2,5,3)=30$, we can write these periods as
$\frac{15}{30}, \frac{12}{30},\frac{10}{30}$.

Since $\operatorname{lcm}(15,12,10)=60$, the lcm of the periods is $\frac{60}{30}=2$.